# How to Lazy Load a static library?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, lazy-loading

I am working on a project that involves card swiping on different types of swipers from different vendors. These swipers have their own static libraries. I had no issues in integrating these libraries in my project i.e. everything was fine at compile time, but at runtime they start behaving unexpectedly. This is due to the fact that these libraries have a common entry point, so something is going wrong and some APIs are getting called when they should not be.

All I can think of to resolve this issue is lazy loading a library. But is this really possible in iOS because all I know is lazy loading is with dynamic libraries. If possible then how? Or is there any other way to solve my issue?

Comment: There's no such thing as loading (lazy or not) a static library... this is why it's description is `static`. It gets linked into the same binary with the rest of your application and from then on, it's all one big blob of binary.

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I was wondering. But can you think of any other solution to this? My exact problem is two different swiper libraries when integrated in same project create issues. I cannot debug because they are libraries and I don't have their code.

Comment: Guess you are out of luck, you can't dynamically load libraries in iOS. Other which you could load some part of the app later and bypass the review.

Comment: I guess something you could try is create your own dynamic libraries using the static libraries as their content, but I'm dubious to the suspicion that your issues are caused by linking these libraries in. Library conflicts will generally be discovered at link time, not run time.

Comment: @mah Can I create a separate bundle and put this library into that bundle. Will that work?

Comment: @EvolGate there may be a way to make it work with separate bundles but there would not be and advantage. A bundle is just a formal layout of files in the distribution of your app. As long as code in one bundle can locate another it can generally use the other's resources (though it may be more difficult to find them), but to what advantage? Seriously, I believe you're chasing a red herring and instead need to debug your app -- even though that's made more difficult by not having source to all of it.